# 7687 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (path): stuck at this part in pyinstaller , what solution?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

[

```
how to solve it, i've been trying for days
```

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOSQ6.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suvKO.jpg)

```
how to solve it, i've been trying for days
```

Comment: This is an extremally  poor quality question... please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, `pyinstaller` stuck at `INFO: Extra DLL search directories (PATH)`

Fixed by patching `Lib\site-packages\pyinstaller\isolated\_parent.py` on line #233 (see [original code on github](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/develop/PyInstaller/isolated/_parent.py#L233)

```py
        try:
            self._child.wait(timeout=5)
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            self._child.kill()
```

For some reason the `_child.wait()` in the original code was hanging forever.

Possibly due to deadlock with PIPE when using `.wait()` as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait)